# Best way to translate Django generic view

Tags: django, django-views

I am upgrading to Django 1.5 which has since deprecated generic views. I am using django-voting which used generic views. I am not sure how to translate this into a class based view:

```
from django.conf.urls.defaults import *
from django.views.generic.list_detail import object_list
from django.core.context_processors import request
from django.shortcuts import get_object_or_404, render_to_response
from blog.models import Blog
from voting.views import vote_on_object
from voting.models import Vote
import operator 

urlpatterns = patterns('',

    url(r'^links/(?P<object_id>\d+)/(?P<direction>up|down|clear)vote/?$',
        vote_on_object,
        dict(
            model=Blog,
            template_object_name='link',
            template_name='blog/link_confirm_vote.html',
            allow_xmlhttprequest=True,
            ),
        name="link_vote",)

)
```

Comment: object_list is removed in django 1.5

Answer (score 0):

views.py

```
class BlogDetailView(DetailView):
    model = Blog
    template_name = 'idea/link_confirm_vote.html'
```

urls.py

```
from .views import BlogDetailView   

urlpatterns = patterns('',
    url(
        regex=r'^links/(?P<object_id>\d+)/(?P<direction>up|down|clear)vote/?$',
        view=BlogDetailView.as_view(),
        name='link_vote'
    ),
)
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick response! I think this is the right track however the vote_on_object module is not being recognized. :(

Comment: I looked at this doc before I asked: [Document Link](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/class-based-views/generic-display/#django.views.generic.list.ListView) and I was using the listview, but no dice with that either.